# Gradient color in top border

Tags: html, css

i want to use color gradient  on my top border

i have used this site for generate Gradient color i have done copy and past for code css and i had replaced background with border-top-color  :

its my project :

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/18/)

this is the PSD FILE :
[PSD FILE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/pi5qrgr7qcd6002/2layer.rar)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="carousel" >
                <div class="title">
                    Welcome to ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 1100px;
}
#wrap:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -95px;
    z-index: 9999;
    content: " ";
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://s14.postimg.org/7tmkd1hfl/shadow.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#carousel {
    border:solid 1px #1a1a1a;
    position:relative;
    width:903px;
    height:299px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/l2e24m48x/light.png);
}
body {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
}
.title {
    position:absolute;
    width:883px;
    height:47px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    line-height: 47px;
    border-top:solid  1px ;
    border-top-color: rgba(240,240,240,1);


    border-top-color: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 20%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 22%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 71%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 97%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%);
    border-top-color: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(240,240,240,1)), color-stop(20%, rgba(240,240,240,1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(250,250,250,1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(250,250,250,1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(230,230,230,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(230,230,230,1)));
    border-top-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 20%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 22%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 71%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 97%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%);
    border-top-color: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 20%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 22%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 71%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 97%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%);
    border-top-color: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 20%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 22%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 71%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 97%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%);
    border-top-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(240,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 20%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 22%, rgba(250,250,250,1) 71%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 97%, rgba(230,230,230,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#e6e6e6', GradientType=1 );


    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 12 ;
    padding-left: 19px;
    font-style: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background:url(images/title.png) bottom left repeat;
}
```

so my probleme  is that i don't have gradient color but just white color

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i haven't the gradient color just white color no gradient like the screen shot

Comment: If you're using an image for the background of that div, you might as well just include the border in the image.

Comment: but the border is not include with the div text he is alone in photoshop and i find exporting only the border not normal ?

Comment: The border would just be part of the background image for the div.

Comment: OKEY another screenshot why are you sure ? http://s10.postimg.org/wzroq3sg9/border.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/19/)**

Best way is to use `<hr>`

css

```
top_line { 
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 47px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin:0;
    background: black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(transparent), to(transparent), color-stop(50%, white));
}
```

html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="carousel">
        <hr class="top_line" />
        <div class="title">Welcome to ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also do this with [Read here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/)

---

From given psd

there are 3 elements basically

1. gradient block
2. gradient top border
3. 3 sides border gradient

From my demo above you get the #2, #3 is already achieved, #1 is achieved if you follow the link I have attached to read.

Here is your psd parts

[image]

Comment: Your answer is not like what i want please look  at the screenshot

Comment: Can you please explain? Its really difficult to make it out from the image.

Comment: ok this is the psd file and you will more understand what i want http://www.mediafire.com/download/pi5qrgr7qcd6002/2layer.rar

Comment: Your PSD does not clarify anything.

Comment: i want make like the light nav menu top in the psd file

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it this way

HTML:

```
    <div class="title">
        <div class='backTitle'></div>
        Welcome to  ...
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.backTitle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #888, #cccccc, #888);
    margin-left: -19px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.title {
    position:absolute;
    width:883px;
    height:47px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    line-height: 47px;
    border-top:solid  5px black;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 12 ;
    padding-left: 19px;
    font-style: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/s4bzqt7up/title.png) bottom left repeat  ;
}
```

Comment: please look at the screenshot on the final of my question

Comment: sorry, I can't really see the specific gradient you want in those images...exactly what element (by id or class) do you want the gradient in or on top of? From your CSS it looked as if you wanted border-top of .title to have a gradient.

Comment: this is the PSD file http://www.mediafire.com/download/pi5qrgr7qcd6002/2layer.rar and you will see these layers